# When using an action bar, how can I show a toast (on long press) for items with an action view set?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am adding to the action bar menu dynamically and using a custom [ActionView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView) which is set when the item is created.

The action view is used, so that I can use a custom view (rather than a simple drawable), which has some logic to control how it is displayed.

The problem is that there is no toast shown when long pressing on these items. I believe this might be something to do with the click event not being passed through to the underlying action bar. The item doesn't show the selectable background, like static menu items do and doesn't trigger `onOptionsItemSelected` when clicked, I have to manually set a click listener to the action view.

This is a code example of when I add the menu item.

```
    MenuItem item = _menu.findItem(obj.getId());
    if(item == null)
        item = _menu.add(Menu.NONE, obj.getId(), Menu.NONE, obj.getName());

    item.setTitleCondensed(obj.getName().substring(0,1));
    item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    item.setTitle(obj.getName());

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = item.getActionView();
    if(v == null)
        v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.favourite_obj, null);

    if(obj.getName().length() > 0){
        ColourIndicator letter = (ColourIndicator) v.findViewById(R.id.colour);
        letter.setColour(obj.getColour());

        item.setActionView(v);

        final Obj o = obj;
        item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                // this does not fire
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
```

I have found next to no resources around this, so I can only assume there is a simple solution that I can't see.